# Per-User Database pattern and Cloudant

Tags: couchdb, cloudant, nosql

Since CouchDb based databases, like Cloudant, provide a Per-Database security model and not a Per-Document one, I have to go for a Per-User Database pattern in order to fulfill my security requirements.

Considering that in practice, **a single Cloudant account contains all the DBs for a single app** (mix DBs from different apps is a not a good solution to me):

What if I want to create another app? How can I solve this problem?

Should I create a new Cloudant account for each application? Is it possible/feasible?

Are there other ways or best practices to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the DB per user model, when creating a new application if you don't want data shared across apps, and want to be able to reuse the names used in your db naming scheme eg each database is named using usernames. Creating a new Cloudant account for that app is the way to go. It is certainly feasible and possible to have multiple accounts.